# Avoid repeating questions for different categories in Quiz App

Tags: ios, iphone

In this quiz app I would like to avoid repeating questions. There are ten categories with 17 questions each. I tried to use an array where the selected question number is stored.

How can I have `QuestionSelected` be a number that has not previously been stored in the array? Right now it does not work..

```
CategoryLoaded = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] integerForKey:@"CategorySaved"];

NSMutableArray *testArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:1];
NSMutableArray *cat1 = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:1];
NSMutableArray *cat2 = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:1];
NSMutableArray *cat3 = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:1];
NSMutableArray *cat4 = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:1];
NSMutableArray *cat5 = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:1];
NSMutableArray *cat6 = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:1];
NSMutableArray *cat7 = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:1];
NSMutableArray *cat8 = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:1];
NSMutableArray *cat9 = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:1];
NSMutableArray *cat10 = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:1];


switch(CategoryLoaded)
{
    case 1: testArray = cat1;
        break;
    case 2: testArray = cat2;
        break;
    case 3: testArray = cat3;
        break;
    case 4: testArray = cat4;
        break;
    case 5: testArray = cat5;
        break;
    case 6: testArray = cat6;
        break;
    case 7: testArray = cat7;
        break;
    case 8: testArray = cat8;
        break;
    case 9: testArray = cat9;
        break;
    case 10: testArray = cat10;
        break;
}

int test = arc4random() %17;
while([testArray containsObject: @"test"])
{
    test = arc4random()%17;
}

QuestionSelected = test;
```

Comment: Please [edit] to add a specific problem statement — "it doesn't work" can be assumed, but *how* does it not work? What error message or incorrect behavior is characteristic?

Comment: You're waaaay over-complicating things... I'd recommend storing the questions in an array then removing the question asked.

Comment: Get index from modulo between random number and array length, get the value at index, delete the item at the index. I don't have the IOS knowledge to write anything else than pseudo code here though.